# Animating UIView isHidden subviews

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift3

I have a UIView `EmptyCollectionView`, which I display when my UICollectionView is empty. The way I have this working is that I create the UIView and `addSubview` in viewDidLoad of my ViewController, then change toggle isHidden property of the view (as well as the collectionview) as needed.

I'd like to polish things up a little now I have the core function working, and I wan't to add some subtle animation to the subviews contained in my empty view, such as making the contained `imageview` bounce on display.

So my question is, what is the best way to detect when the `UIView` is being shown (i.e. is there a `viewDidAppear` type callback I could use)?

Supplementary question: I'm new to this... Is adding the empty view and toggling the isHidden property a good way of doing this? Or should I be doing it a different way? (i.e. should I instead be creating and destroying the view as needed, rather than keeping it around)

Thanks

Comment: you can animate `UIView` constraints changing, or `UIView` alpha

Answer (score 32):

The best way in my opinion is to extend UIView

```
extension UIView {
    
    func fadeIn(_ duration: TimeInterval = 0.2, onCompletion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        self.alpha = 0
        self.isHidden = false
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration,
                       animations: { self.alpha = 1 },
                       completion: { (value: Bool) in
                          if let complete = onCompletion { complete() }
                       }
        )
    }
    
    func fadeOut(_ duration: TimeInterval = 0.2, onCompletion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration,
                       animations: { self.alpha = 0 },
                       completion: { (value: Bool) in
                           self.isHidden = true
                           if let complete = onCompletion { complete() }
                       }
        )
    }
    
}
```

So you just have to call `view.fadeIn()` for a default 0.2 sec animation, or `view.fadeIn(1)` to make it last one second.

You can even add a completion event:

```
view.fadeOut(0.5, onCompletion: {
    print("Animation completed, do whatever you want")
})
```

Comment: this is a really smart solution

Comment: HOWEVER, rather than "`if let complete = onCompletion { complete() }`"
, just do "`complete?()`". The questionmark tests for nil without the if-statement.

Answer (score 17):

This works, I hope it can help you. To hide view:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3/*Animation Duration second*/, animations: {
     self.EmptyCollectionView.alpha = 0
}, completion:  {
   (value: Bool) in
       self.EmptyCollectionView.isHidden = true
})
```

To show view:

```
self.EmptyCollectionView.isHidden = false
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
         self.EmptyCollectionView.alpha = 1
    }, completion:  nil)
```

Comment: May I know in ShowView completion: Why you didn't set .isHidden to fals back again??

Answer (score 17):

Swift 4.2 extension to allow animation when setting isHidden on any UIView class:

```
extension UIView {
    func setIsHidden(_ hidden: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        if animated {
            if self.isHidden && !hidden {
                self.alpha = 0.0
                self.isHidden = false
            }
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                self.alpha = hidden ? 0.0 : 1.0
            }) { (complete) in
                self.isHidden = hidden
            }
        } else {
            self.isHidden = hidden
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can animate the alpha property of EmptyCollectionView to either 0 to hide or 1 to show

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) { 
    self.EmptyCollectionView.alpha = 0
}
```

Also make sure that **isOpaque** property is set to False to enable Transparency of the view

Comment: But i want to animate the subviews NOT the view itself. My emptyview contains an imageview, when emptyview shows or hides, I want to animate the imageview. I've fixed it by just adding a show & hide function that sets `self.isHidden` and does the animation. Annoying because now some views use `isHidden = false` and others use `view.show()`, seems a bit messy but it works for now

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5

```
import UIKit

extension UIView {
    
    func animateSetHidden(_ hidden: Bool, duration: CGFloat = CATransaction.animationDuration(), completion: @escaping (Bool)->() = { _ in}) {
        
        if duration > 0 {

            if self.isHidden && !hidden {
                self.alpha = 0
                self.isHidden = false
            } 
            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay:0, options: .beginFromCurrentState) {
            
                self.alpha = hidden ? 0 : 1
            
            } completion: { c in
          
                if c {
                    self.isHidden = hidden
                }
                completion(c)
            
            }

        } else {
            
            self.isHidden = hidden
            self.alpha = hidden ? 0 : 1
            completion(true)

        }
        
    }

}
```